# Sets of Polynomial roots

Tags: algebra-precalculus

For a real number $k,$ let $A$ be the set of roots of $$x^2 + (k - 1) x - 2(k + 1) = 0,$$and let $B$ be the set of roots of $$(k - 1) x^2 + kx + 1 = 0.$$(These roots may be complex.) Find the number of values of $k$ so that $|A \cup B| = 3.$

I don't know how to start this. Can someone help?

Comment: If that union has three elements, then $|A\cap B|=1$. Therefore the two polynomials must have non-constant gcd but not be multiple of each other. Just do long division (divide the non-monic by the monic for convenience) and impose that the remainder divides them, but is non-zero.

Comment: @logarithm What if one of them has repeated roots?

Comment: The most straightforward approach would be to write the roots of each equation in terms of $k$ using the quadratic formula. From there you can handle all the situations that may lead to the desired condition $|A \cup B| = 3$.

Answer (score 1):

The roots of the two equations are
$$\frac{1}{2}\left(-(k-1) \pm \sqrt{(k-1)^2 + 8 (k+1)}\right) = \frac{1}{2}(-(k-1) \pm (k+3)) = \{2, -(k+1)\}$$
$$\frac{1}{2(k-1)} \left(-k \pm \sqrt{k^2 - 4(k-1)}\right) = \frac{1}{2(k-1)}(-k \pm (k-2)) = \{-\frac{1}{k-1}, -1\}$$
so you want
$$\{2, -(k+1), -\frac{1}{k-1}, -1\}$$
to have cardinality $3$.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Observe that by the fundamental theorem of algebra, every polynomial of degree 2 has 2 roots. Therefore, if we have 2 polynomials of degree 2, we need one of them to have a root with multiplicity and not the other one. The quadratic formula will be useful here.

Edit: Matthew pointed out that it could be possible that they both have two roots, but one in common. I was mistaken.

Comment: Why couldn't each polynomial have two roots but they have one root in common?

Comment: They can. You are absolutely correct.